# How do I replace newlines with their escape sequence using awk?

Tags: awk

I'm asking for an awk solution because the sed solution `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` does NOT get the last newline character usually present in files. My problem is that if I have a stream of data, every single newline character INCLUDING the one usually present at the end of outputs generated by programs like `echo` needs to be replaced with `\n` (raw). `tr` does not work because it cannot substitute in strings (which `\\n` is), only individual characters.

As example, upon piping:

```
echo -e "This is\na test."
```

to awk, I ought to get:

```
This is\na test.\n
```

in return.

Comment: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g;$s/$/\\n/'`

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. Any time you try to use sed commands other than s, g, and/or p (with -n) you are using constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo -e "This is\na test." | awk -v ORS='\\n' '1'
This is\na test.\n$
```

The `$` at the end of the output is my prompt.